# How to save Image or Png of graphics created in Panel control?

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code, I am creating graphics and trying to draw rectangles and lines. I am getting desired output. Finally I want to export the sketch to image file or Png file. I have tried the following it is saving a blank white background png ([Png file that is getting exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwrF9.png)
) but not capturing the actual sketch. Whereas in Run time, in Panel1 control, sketch is being generated and visible

```
Private Sub Button19_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button19.Click

    For d = 1 To 72 Step 1

        g = Panel1.CreateGraphics
        Dim re As New System.Drawing.Rectangle
        re.X = 10 * d
        re.Y = 50
        re.Height = 40
        re.Width = 1
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, re)

        Dim pen1 As New System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red, 1)
        Dim pen2 As New System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Yellow, 1)
        Dim pen3 As New System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Blue, 1)

        ' draw lines representing bottom side of coil 

        For P3 = 1 To 6 Step 1

            g.DrawLine(pen1, 5 + 10 * P3, 30, 5 + 10 * P3, 100)

        Next

        For p4 = 7 To 12 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen2, 5 + 10 * p4, 30, 5 + 10 * p4, 100)
        Next

        For p5 = 13 To 18 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen3, 5 + 10 * p5, 30, 5 + 10 * p5, 100)
        Next

        For P3 = 19 To 24 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen1, 5 + 10 * P3, 30, 5 + 10 * P3, 100)

        Next

        For p4 = 25 To 30 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen2, 5 + 10 * p4, 30, 5 + 10 * p4, 100)
        Next

        For p5 = 31 To 36 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen3, 5 + 10 * p5, 30, 5 + 10 * p5, 100)
        Next

        For P3 = 37 To 42 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen1, 5 + 10 * P3, 30, 5 + 10 * P3, 100)

        Next

        For p4 = 43 To 48 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen2, 5 + 10 * p4, 30, 5 + 10 * p4, 100)
        Next

        For p5 = 49 To 54 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen3, 5 + 10 * p5, 30, 5 + 10 * p5, 100)
        Next

        For P3 = 55 To 60 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen1, 5 + 10 * P3, 30, 5 + 10 * P3, 100)

        Next

        For p4 = 61 To 65 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen2, 5 + 10 * p4, 30, 5 + 10 * p4, 100)
        Next

        For p5 = 66 To 72 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen3, 5 + 10 * p5, 30, 5 + 10 * p5, 100)
        Next

        ' draw lines representing top side of coil
        Dim pitch As Integer = 15

        For P3 = 1 + pitch To 6 + pitch Step 1

            g.DrawLine(pen1, 7 + 10 * P3, 30, 7 + 10 * P3, 100)

        Next

        For p4 = 7 + pitch To 12 + pitch Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen2, 7 + 10 * p4, 30, 7 + 10 * p4, 100)
        Next

        For p5 = 13 + pitch To 18 + pitch Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen3, 7 + 10 * p5, 30, 7 + 10 * p5, 100)
        Next

        For P3 = 19 + pitch To 24 + pitch Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen1, 7 + 10 * P3, 30, 7 + 10 * P3, 100)

        Next

        For p4 = 25 + pitch To 30 + pitch Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen2, 7 + 10 * p4, 30, 7 + 10 * p4, 100)
        Next

        For p5 = 31 + pitch To 36 + pitch Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen3, 7 + 10 * p5, 30, 7 + 10 * p5, 100)
        Next

        For P3 = 37 + pitch To 42 + pitch Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen1, 7 + 10 * P3, 30, 7 + 10 * P3, 100)

        Next

        For p4 = 43 + pitch To 48 + pitch Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen2, 7 + 10 * p4, 30, 7 + 10 * p4, 100)
        Next

        For p5 = 49 + pitch To 54 + pitch Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen3, 7 + 10 * p5, 30, 7 + 10 * p5, 100)
        Next

        For P3 = 55 + pitch To 72 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen1, 7 + 10 * P3, 30, 7 + 10 * P3, 100)

        Next

        For P3 = 1 To 4 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen1, 7 + 10 * P3, 30, 7 + 10 * P3, 100)

        Next


        For p4 = 61 + pitch - 72 To 65 + pitch - 72 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen2, 7 + 10 * p4, 30, 7 + 10 * p4, 100)
        Next

        For p5 = 66 + pitch - 72 To 72 + pitch - 72 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(pen3, 7 + 10 * p5, 30, 7 + 10 * p5, 100)
        Next

        ' connection lines on top

        'For P3 = 1 To 6 Step 1

        '        g.DrawLine(pen1, 5 + 10 * P3, 30, 5 + 10 * P3 + 3 + 5 * P3, 40)

        '    Next


        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
        ' g.DrawImage(bmp, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))
        'g.FillRectangle(SolidBrush(Color.Blue), New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))



        Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))

        bmp.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "winding diagram.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You should never call `CreateGraphics`. You should handle the `Paint` event of the relevant control. You can write a method that takes a `Graphics` object as an argument and draws with it. You can then pass it `e.Graphics` from that `Paint` event handler and the result of calling `Graphics.FromImage` to draw on an `Image`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution suggested. Sorry I am electrical engineer and not very much proficient with programming and hence could not understand corrections suggested. Could you please suggest how my code should be re-written?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using `e.Graphics` that is supplied to you in the `Paint()` event:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
        Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, Panel1.ClientRectangle)
        Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "winding diagram.png")
        bmp.Save(FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        MessageBox.Show("Image saved to: " & FileName)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics

        For d = 1 To 72 Step 1
            Dim re As New System.Drawing.Rectangle(New Point(10 * d, 50), New Size(1, 40))
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, re)
        Next

        Dim curPen As Pen = Pens.Black
        For P As Integer = 1 To 72
            Select Case P
                Case 1 To 6, 19 To 24, 37 To 42, 55 To 60
                    curPen = Pens.Red
                Case 7 To 12, 25 To 30, 43 To 48, 61 To 65
                    curPen = Pens.Yellow
                Case 13 To 18, 31 To 36, 49 To 54, 66 To 72
                    curPen = Pens.Blue
            End Select
            g.DrawLine(curPen, 5 + 10 * P, 30, 5 + 10 * P, 100)
        Next

        ' draw lines representing top side of coil
        Dim pitch As Integer = 15
        For P As Integer = (1 + pitch) To 72
            Select Case P
                Case 1 + pitch To 6 + pitch, 19 + pitch To 24 + pitch, 37 + pitch To 42 + pitch, 55 + pitch To 72
                    curPen = Pens.Red
                Case 7 + pitch To 12 + pitch, 25 + pitch To 30 + pitch, 43 + pitch To 48 + pitch
                    curPen = Pens.Yellow
                Case 13 + pitch To 18 + pitch, 31 + pitch To 36 + pitch, 49 + pitch To 54 + pitch
                    curPen = Pens.Blue
            End Select
            g.DrawLine(curPen, 7 + 10 * P, 30, 7 + 10 * P, 100)
        Next

        For P3 As Integer = 1 To 4 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 7 + 10 * P3, 30, 7 + 10 * P3, 100)
        Next

        For p4 As Integer = 61 + pitch - 72 To 65 + pitch - 72 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 7 + 10 * p4, 30, 7 + 10 * p4, 100)
        Next

        For p5 As Integer = 66 + pitch - 72 To 72 + pitch - 72 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 7 + 10 * p5, 30, 7 + 10 * p5, 100)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Resulting image: *I used the same size as your blank image from your question.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Problem is solved. Thank you for showing the correct way of doing it. You have made by day :) thanks once again